# Foreign key constraint violation in tests but not in practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I'm receiving a foreign key constraint error in Rspec but not in practice when testing my destroy action on my Users model.

I'm not cascading since I want objects created by deleted users to remain in the database. Instead, I've written a custom method to reassign any objects that belong to the user being deleted to the user performing the deletion.

I'm calling `delete :destroy, id: @user` in my tests.

The following is my controller action and the helper to prevent foreign key constraints.

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @flash_message = String.new # this is used by the next method in case we do cleanup.
  clean_up_before_delete
  unless @user == current_user
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'User deleted.' + @flash_message
    redirect_to users_url
  else
    flash[:danger] = "You can't delete yourself."
    redirect_to users_url
  end
end


def clean_up_before_delete
 # this prevents us from having orphaned comments, histories and work_items
 unless @user.work_items.blank?
   @user.work_items.each do |w|
     w.user_id = current_user.id
     w.owned = false
     w.save
   end
   @flash_message = ' Work items reassigned to queue.'
 end

 @comments = Comment.where(user_id: @user.id)
 unless @comments.blank?
   @comments.each do |c|
     c.body += " (Original commenter #{@user.name} was deleted.)"
     c.user_id = current_user.id
     c.save
   end
 end

  @histories = History.where(user_id: @user.id)
  unless @histories.blank?
    @histories.each do |h|
      h.body += " (Original user #{@user.name} was deleted.)"
      h.user_id = current_user.id
      h.save
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the error I am receiving:
`ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:         ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_a9cab3453b" on table "work_items"`

I'm able to delete users without receiving this error if I do it in an actual web browser - the problem only seems to happen in Rspec. Am I missing something?

Here is the HAML in my view:

```
- if !current_user?(user)
   = link_to "Delete", user,                                          
              method: :delete,                                                 
              data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{user.name}?" }, 
              class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger"
```

Comment: Are you using database_cleaner?  What mechanism is RSpec using between runs to reset the DB?  The code you're providing above will only run when destroying users via the controller.  Between them, RSpec and Rails may wish to destroy users in many other contexts.

Comment: I'm strictly using fixtures for these tests, so it shouldn't matter, but I just dropped and recreated the DB now and received the same error. The way my test is written(`delete :destroy, id: @user`), it should be sending an HTTP `DELETE` to the `destroy` action in my controller, which is the same thing the browser is doing.

Comment: You might find this easier to test by moving the `clean_up_before_delete` method into the `User` model and testing it there.

Comment: @zetetic - great idea. I probably should have done that in the first place - it's far more Rails-ish. Set it up as a callback and my controller test also passes now. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out the problem was the fixture I was using for current_user in my test didn't have an ID assigned, just in case anyone was wondering why it didn't work in the controller.

Comment: Had a similar problem testing my controller using `Minitest` and it also was a fixture problem.